# Fontis Westpac bug - can't open API file

Tags: payment-gateway

apologise is the answer is incredibly obvious.

So, I am testing a new site, which is just sitting in a subfolder from our root URL.
Let's say it's sitting in /mage19.
I've installed Fontis Westpac, added in our credentials and trying to run a charge to test it. However the charge isn't working (with no useful info passed to the customer)

Looking at the logs I can see it can't open the Qvalent API file. I tried changing the path in the source (adding a leading slash) to no avail. In any case the code base is the same between both sites.

Would appreciate any help!

```
2014-12-15T23:24:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/Api/Qvalent_PayWayAPI.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in    /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src/Fontis_Westpac_Model_PayWay_Api.php on line 23
2014-12-15T23:24:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/Api/Qvalent_PayWayAPI.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src/Fontis_Westpac_Model_PayWay_Api.php on line 23
2014-12-15T23:24:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/Api/Qvalent_PayWayAPI.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src/Fontis_Westpac_Model_PayWay_Api.php on line 23
2014-12-15T23:24:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/Api/Qvalent_PayWayAPI.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src/Fontis_Westpac_Model_PayWay_Api.php on line 23
2014-12-15T23:24:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/Api/Qvalent_PayWayAPI.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src/Fontis_Westpac_Model_PayWay_Api.php on line 23
2014-12-15T23:24:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/Api/Qvalent_PayWayAPI.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src/Fontis_Westpac_Model_PayWay_Api.php on line 23
2014-12-15T23:24:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src/Qvalent_PayWayAPI.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2014-12-15T23:24:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src/Qvalent_PayWayAPI.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
```

Looking at the credit card API log (ccapi.log), it seems all the library files are loaded and also this indicates the cert is loaded ok:

```
2014-12-16 05:58:22.975 <Init> URL = https://ccapi.client.qvalent.com/payway/ccapi
2014-12-16 05:58:22.975 <Init> socketTimeout = 60000ms
2014-12-16 05:58:22.975 <Init> Loading certificate from file /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19//var/certs/ccapi.pem
2014-12-16 05:58:22.976 <Init> Certificate serial number: 51735BD1
2014-12-16 05:58:22.976 <Init> Certificate valid to: 21-Apr-2015 03:24:01
2014-12-16 05:58:22.976 <Init> Loading CA certificates from file /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/app/code/community/Fontis/Westpac/Model/PayWay/Api/cacerts.crt
2014-12-16 05:58:22.976 <Init> Initialisation complete
```

The system log shows:

```
2014-12-16T05:59:20+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3941
```

I also get this in the system log: can't explain where Qvalent/PayWayAPI.php could be coming from e.g. Qvalent as a folder.

```
2014-12-16T06:27:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Qvalent/PayWayAPI.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2014-12-16T06:27:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Qvalent/PayWayAPI.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/app/code/local:/home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/app/code/community:/home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/app/code/core:/home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

Absolutely cannot pin this down.

Compiler disabled, caches disabled, cleared caches, re-enabled.

Is the below log file output of any use?

```
2014-12-16T23:51:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Qvalent/PayWayAPI.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/gooleys/public_html/mage19/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

That would indicate that Qvalent_PayWayAPI.php is somehow being changed to a path? I.e. Varien Autoload is changing a file name character (e.g. _ ) into a directory separator?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to recompile Magento (In Admin under System > Tools > Compilation) after installing a new extension. It may also be a good idea to disable it whilst debugging this issue if that doesn't resolve it.

Comment: Hi Jasuten, tried all that. Turned off, recompiled, no joy. Caches turned off too.